# How to add a new date column derived from existing date column based on the shelf life of the products to my csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

| Room | rack | type | no.of items | manufacturing date | expiry date(new column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | LLQ | 6 | 21/3/2021 | - |
| 1 | 2 | AZK | 6 | 21/3/2021 | - |
| 1 | 2 | CHD | 6 | 21/3/2021 | - |

- LLQ: expires in 21 days
- AZK: expires in 10 days
- CHD: expires in 30 days

How do I use pandas to derive the corresponding expiry dates based on the product shelf life? Pls help, I am new to python, basically coding in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
d={'LLQ':21,'AZK':10,'CHD':30}
df['expires']=df['type'].apply(lambda x:d[x])
```

From The above code we created a column names 'expires'

Now make use of `pd.to_datetime()` method and convert your 'manufacture date' to datetime and use `apply()` method and `pd.offsets.Dateoffsets()` method:

```
df['manufacturing date']=df['manufacturing date']=pd.to_datetime(df['manufacturing date'])
df['expiry date']=df.apply(lambda x:x['manufacturing date']+pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=x['expires']),1)
```

Now If you print df you will get your desired output:

```
    Room    rack    type    no.of items manufacturing date    expires    expiry date
0   1       2       LLQ     6           2021-03-21              21       2021-04-11
1   1       2       AZK     6           2021-03-21              10       2021-03-31
2   1       2       CHD     6           2021-03-21              30       2021-04-20
```

Now If you want to save/update it to a csv then use [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
df.to_csv('filepath/filename.csv',index=False)
```

**Note:** the above update your csv file but previously stored data is removed

Comment: Yeah It is possible just use `drop()` method and remove unwanted columns and then use `to_csv()` method and update your csv file

Comment: Sorry 1 more thing, I managed to get the harvest dates and stuff, but how do i get it updated in my csv file using pandas?  Or should I redo using csv reader/writer

Comment: Updated my answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Date data from csv is recognized as a string. So you first convert it into datetime format

```
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta 

df['LLQ'] = df['manufacturing date'].apply(lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y") + timedelta(days=21)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Do same works for other calculations.